# AddFieldToFilter And inside OR condition

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, query

I want to achieve the following query in magento custom model.

```
select * form calendar where date >='2015-04-13' AND start_date <='2015-04-14' AND (is_available != 1 or  (is_available == 1 and rooms_avil<=0))
```

How to achieve this in magento with AddFieldToFilter ? Not AddAttributeToFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Method **addAttributeToFilter** is used for module whose model supports EAV structure like: catalog/category, catalog/product etc.
We generally use **addFieldToFitler** for custom module (**whose model doesn’t support EAV structure**)

Answering on your question: how to create

> condition OR (condition AND condition)

I think you can't do it using addFieldToFilter. So my advice is:

```
->getSelect()->where( /* put here all of your conditions */)
```